# php mail not delivering to email

Tags: email, php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <link href="aadab.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.png">

</head>

<body>

<h2>REGISTRATION FORM</h2>

<div id="form">

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        $name= $_POST['name'];
        $phone= $_POST['phone'];
        $email= $_POST['email'];
        $college= $_POST['namecolg'];
        $team= $_POST['team'];
        $im= $_POST['im'];
        $detail= $_POST['detail'];
        $subject= 'Registration for aadab 2013';

        if ( (empty($name)) || (empty($phone)) || (empty($email)) || (empty($college)) || (empty($detail)) )
            {
                echo '<p id="fillall">It is necessary that you fill at least the required fields that are marked with a star</p>';
            }
        else
            {
                $to= 'xyz@gmail.com';
                $con= "<b>Registration Details:</b><br>"."Name: $name<br>"."Contact: $phone<br>"."Email: $email<br>"."College: $college<br>"."Team(if any): $team<br>"."Instant message: $im<br>"."Details of the event(s): $detail<br>";

                $emsg= "Registration Details:\n\n"."Name: $name\n"."Contact: $phone\n"."Email: $email\n"."College: $college\n"."Team(if any): $team\n"."Instant message: $im\n"."Details of the event(s): $detail\n";   

                $msg = wordwrap($emsg,70);

                $mailsend= mail($to, $subject, $msg);

                if ($mailsend)
                {
                    echo "<div class=\"regdet\"><b>Here is what you've submitted:</b><br><br>$con";
                    echo '<br>Congratulations! You have successfully registered! Click <a href="index.html">here</a> to continue.</div>';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<div class="regdet"><br>OOPS! Something went wrong. Click <a href="form.php">here</a> to try again.</div>';
                }
            }
    }
else
    {?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" autocomplete="on" method="post">

    <table>


        <tr>
            <th><label for="name">Your fullname*</label></th>
            <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" required></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th><label for="phone">Your contact number*</label></th>
            <td><input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>" required></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th><label for="email">Your email-id*</label></th>
            <td><input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" required></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th><label for="namecolg">Name of your college*</label></th>
            <td><input type="text" id="namecolg" name="namecolg" value="<?php echo $college; ?>" required></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th><label for="team">The name of your team<br>(if registering for a team event)</label></th>
            <td><input type="text" id="team" name="team" value="<?php echo $team; ?>" ></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th><label for="im">Bbm pin/iMessage id/Whatsapp<br>(if any, separate each id by a comma)</label></th>
            <td><input type="text" id="im" name="im" value="<?php echo $im; ?>" ></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th><label for="detail">Details of the event(s) you want to register for*</label></th>
            <td><input type="text" id="detail" name="detail" value="<?php echo $detail; ?>" required></td>
        </tr>

        <tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align: center; padding: 40px 0px 0px 0px;"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"></td</tr>

    </table>


</form>

<?php } ?>

</div>


</body>

</html>
```

this piece of script has baffled me for two days !
i am unable to find a bug which is not allowing me to send an email to my email id

firebug also does not show any warnings or error
i checked phpcodechecker.com for possible syntax errrors but nothing came up

im unable to receive maill from neither a live server nor my local zend server
in both cases i get the "else" echo statement..

Comment: Are you sure mail() is allowed in your php.ini file?

Comment: Do you have a mail server set up on your machine and is it configured in php.ini?

Comment: yes it is .. on the live server iv temporary used a new directory for this form .. because the server already contains an existing website which is able to send an email without an issue.. but this form never sends any email..

Answer (score 2):

If you know **for a fact** that mail is setup **and** allowed on your server, try sending a test email just to make sure your variables aren't creating the error. Do something like this:

```
$test = mail('your@email.com', 'Test Email', 'Hope this works!');
if ( $test ) { echo 'Yay it worked!'; }
else { echo 'Oh no mail failed!'; }
```

If you do not know for a fact that mail is setup and enabled, then do the following: 
First, run `phpinfo();` and see what the path to your php.ini file is. Next, look for a line that says `disabled_functions` and see if it contains the word `mail`. If it does, simply remove the `mail` keyword from this line and it will enable the mail() function. If you are unable to access your php.ini, you may wish to contact your webhost and ask if they can manually enable it for you.

However, if no send-path has been setup, it will be a lot harder to get mail() to work. If this is the case, you may want to look into using a 3rd party mailer, such as [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). Personally, I use SwiftMailer even though php's mail() function *is* enabled for me. It makes headers and other things easier, in my opinion.

UPDATE BASED ON FAILED mail() FUNCTION:

In this case, run `phpinfo();` and look in the 6th row. It should say `Configuration File (php.ini) Path`. Then use the supplied path to display the contents of the php.ini file by doing this:

```
echo str_replace("\n", '<br />', file_get_contents('/PATH_TO_CONFIG/php.ini'));
```

Now, just replace PATH_TO_CONFIG with the path supplied in by the `phpinfo()` function. Alternatively, you can rely on the `php_ini_loaded_file()` function to return the path and retrieve it that way. So you could also do this:

```
echo str_replace("\n", '<br />', file_get_contents(php_ini_loaded_file()));
```

Then, search the document for `disabled_functions` and see if `mail` is in there. If not, I would guess that a send-path has not been setup on your server.

UPDATE FOR WIN64:
Try putting this in your configuration:

```
[mail function]
SMTP = mail.yourdomain.com
sendmail_from = admin@yourdomain.com
```

Comment: oh no mail failed.

    <?php
    $test = mail('your@email.com', 'Test Email', 'Hope this works!');
    if ( $test ) { echo 'Yay it worked!'; }
    else { echo 'Oh no mail failed!'; }
    ?>

Comment: I have updated my answer with steps to follow in this case. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: i checked and under [mail function] i can see only configuration for Win32 ... and im running Win64 ... would that be a problem ?

Comment: Win64 actually makes creating a send-path much easier. I have updated my answer again, hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

First of all `mail()` function isn't able to check if the e-mail reached the mailbox.
But your script returned a false on `mail()` so its something on the serverside.

- Do you've a mail server running on your (local) server?
- could php connect to this mail server (see php.ini smtp section if you're running a windows server or take a look at the error logs of your linux mail server)?
- take a look at the error logs of php

And yes, take a look at `phpinfo()` for disabled functions on both servers.
Sometimes you aren't allowed to send a mail if you're on a shared server.
most likely you can't send mail from a local domain to another mail server because this may be an unqualified or illegal domain (will be marked as spam)

and last but not least, download a [phpmailer class](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/), its much easier to use and you don't have to worry much about mail-headers

Comment: i followed your advice but now a new problem has come up: Mailer Error: Could not instantiate mail function.

Comment: Have you googled the error? 
If not, its much easier (for us) to google it first and then ask us ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the function for sending mail in PHP:

```
mail(to,subject,message,headers,parameters)
```

`to`, `subject` and `message` are all required parameters. You are missing a subject.

`headers` and `parameters` are optional

For additional details on how to use the `mail()` function, see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: this is the first time ive experienced such a thing